# Ember.js template binding performance

Tags: performance, data-binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

We have a page containing a table with 26 rows.  Each row will contain either an `<input>` or `<select>` element, depending on the data we're binding to.  When binding to  elements that contain between 5-30 options, it takes a page about 5 seconds to render.  If I remove the  binding, the page renders in under a second.

Is there a known performance issue when binding to Ember.Select views?  Or, could I be doing it incorrectly?  I'm using Firefox 22.  IE9 is about twice as slow.  The CPU is not pegged during this time.  I'm using ember 1.0rc6.

Template snippet:

```
{{#if pa.isPickList}}
    {{view Ember.Select viewName="select" contentBinding="pa.options" selectionBinding="pa.selected"}}
{{else}}
    {{input valueBinding="pa.selected"}}
{{/if}}
```

I worry that the async nature of how I'm fetching the model could be causing inefficiencies.  Perhaps the binding and async events are interacting inefficiently.

Salesforce.com is the backend.  From what little I know about promises, I'm wondering if I need to fetch the server data in a promise.  I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's how I'm currently fetching the data in my Route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        var otherController = this.controllerFor('selectedProducts');

        var ar = Ember.A(); //create an array
        var arg = '0067000000PNWrV';

        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.ProductPricingLookupController.loadOpportunityProducts}',
            arg,
            function myHandler(result, event) { 
            console.info('got results!!! ' + result.length); 
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                var p = result[i];
                var sfProd = App.ProductResult.create({content: p});
                ar.pushObject(sfProd);
            }
            },
            {escape: false} //some of the names have ampersands!!
        );        

        return ar;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie learn the ways of javascript and Ember.

**Update**
[Here is working example of this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/anschoewe/ufAwZ/7/).  I have 5 picklists each with 60 options.  This take 2-3 seconds to render on my machine.  I realize these are decently large numbers but hopefully not unreasonable.  Increase the number of picklist elements or options and you can easily hit 5 seconds.

Also, moving my server-model-fetching to a promise did not affect performance.

Andrew

Comment: this post explains how to add timings to your views, might help track down what takes the longest: http://tobyho.com/2013/03/12/perf-testing-ember.js-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to guess at performance problems like this without looking at it in a profiler. You can try creating a profile in Chrome dev tools to see what method is taking the most amount of time. Or create a jsbin which has the same issue.

One potential issue is that the array that you bind to is being built at the same time when the bindings are connected. This shouldn't be an issue with rc.6. What version of Ember are you on?

Regards to promises, your `model` hook should return a promise that wraps your async call, like so.

```
model: function(params) {
  var promise = Ember.Deferred.create();
  var myHandler = function(result, event) {
    var model = Ember.A();

    // populate the model

    promise.resolve(model)
  }

  var arg = '0067000000PNWrV';
  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(..., myHandler);

  return promise;
}
```

If the bindings were firing too early/often, loading the model in a promise like this would help.

Finally try setting `Ember.STRUCTURED_PROFILE` to true. This will show you exactly how long the templates are taking to render.

### Edit: After the the jsfiddle

I dug into this a little more. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2386) with Ember.Select. The default implementation creates `SelectOption` views for each option inside the select to allow databinding of the option items itself. Creating those many views is what takes the time.

However the typical usage will rarely need binding to the option items only to the whole list itself. And this appears to be the common way to bridge the performance gap.

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sandstrom/5437244) that uses `option` tags instead of `SelectOption` views.

Here's your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8x6y/2/). I upped the lists to 10 with 100 items each. The list renders in about 150ms for me now.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The promise example was very helpful but sadly didn't solve my issue.  I've updated my original question with an example.  Hopefully that helps clarify the problem.

Comment: You, sir, are a rockstar. That solves it.  Thank you.  Hopefully they resolve this by version 1.1.  But, the current workaround (FastSelect) will be fine.